# PhoneGap URL scheme on other pages not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, intel-xdk

Hi i have this simple app and and i use `myapp://` to open app my ANDROID APP this works file but when i use `myapp://index.html` to open a page it does not work i searched the internet but i could not find the solution can any body tell me i want to open a specific page in my APP because TWITTER does not support `myapp://` it supports only if if has any extension like  `myapp://index.html`

or if this is not possible is there any why i could redirect user to a url `myapp://` after login from my TWITTER application

THANKS 
Muhammad Zeeshan

Comment: What does your whitelist look like? What version of cordova are you using? What happens in logcat when you try to open `myapp://index.html`?

Comment: @MBillau i am using intel XDK and i am using CORDOVA 3.x and i am developing in intel XDK so i see no logcat

Comment: You have no logs from the device/emulator at all? I thought you could just type 'monitor' in a `cmd` and it would work.

Comment: @MBillau i know i have no error just want want to know how to use myapp://index.html in my phonegap it only excepts myapp://

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen also http scheme as your site with a listener activity. Something like this code.

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.foursquare.robin.BrowsableActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When any platform re-route your app to your scheme will be revoked shortly.

Answer (score 0):

That myapp:// URL is only useful within the device as a means to start another app on the device (or, in this case, to start your app from another app). I think what you want to do is use a plugin that allows your app to login using the builtin native apps. See this plugin, in particular, as a possible solution: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can make "myapp://" as your mobile app URL scheme using these things :

## Android :

In your menifest.xml file, add intent-filter into  tag

```
 <application ... >
        <activity ... >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Use android:scheme="myapp". So, whenever you want to start your app from other app, you need to add this hiperlink.
Open myApp

## iOS :

In iOS, open .plist file of your project(which can be found in Resources/) in xCode. 
You need to add 2 things :
Information Property List->URL types->item0->URL identifier = Bundle identifier
Information Property List->URL types->item0->URL schemes = myApp

If anything is not there, you can right click and select "add row", then you can type elements. Help will help you. ;)
So, whenever you want to start your app from other app, you need to add this hiperlink.
Open myApp

**Your app will open if it is pre installed in device**

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript frameworks for **single page apps**.
they can handle by easy way that you do not need to request to other url or external file.
all of your application will run in just **single page without refresh**.
here i offer list of this frameworks:

- [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/) ( that is easy to use )
- [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/)
- [angularjs](https://angularjs.org) witch is google project and personally i offer this.
- [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

list of javascript single page framework is mush bigger, but know about these more.

---

**UPDATE**

to handle custom url schema i know some plugins, but personally i did not test theme
 - [Custom URL scheme](http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin)
 -

Comment: @Mohammed Ali i am using TWITTER login in my app so after login user is redirected to the my application i just want a way to support URL myapp:// so that after login user can open my app